# Extract SQL from a Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel 2007 file with data and a Pivot Table. I am migrating the data to a MSSQL database, but I would like to get the SQL from the Pivot Table. There is a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the PivotTable is using a SQL query to get the info from the database, you should be able to click Data->Connections and double-click the connection for the PivotTable, go to Definition, and under Command Text it should have the SQL query.

There's a post about how to use SQL to create a pivot table here:
http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/

If it's not there, check the Command Type in the same window because it might be something like "Cube" which isn't a SQL query, but a connection that was made to an OLAP cube.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All my data is inside the sheet. I am trying to find that 'Cube', but i can't find it. Well, Excel did not generate a 'public' SQL for the pivot table (even than the data is inside the sheet itself)?

Comment: Oh I see.  So if you're data is in the Excel file itself, the SQL query is most-likely something like "SELECT * FROM [mytable]" since PivotTables that use Excel worksheets for the data don't use a special query, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, but I wanna the SQL from the pivot table I generated. Not the raw data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you use a SQL query for a PivotTable, all you're doing is bringing back the data. The PivotTable is what formats the data for how you want it to look. So if you port your data into SQL Server into a table called "MyTable", the SQL query for your pivot table will be "SELECT * FROM MyTable". If you would like to see more about creating a PivotTable from a SQL query, you can check out this article I wrote about it: http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. What I am trying to find is a way to get the SQL (with the Groups, Joins, etc) from the pivot table I created (I am almost sure it wasn't possible).

Comment: Sure thing.  Also, you can rebuild the PivotTable after you have migrated your data to the database.  However, if you have calculated formulas in your pivot table, now THAT'S when you need to do a customized query, which I'm sure people on this board are happy to help with (myself included).  We just need more info.  Can you post a picture of the pivot table? I might be able to help with the SQL query that way.